# Invalid data selection using the findAllRolesById method

Tags: spring-data-jpa, spring-data

I use method **findAllRolesById** for select data from table with param **id=2**.

[image]

When printing the results of the method **findAllRolesById**, I see an incorrect selection for me that I would like to see

[image]

I expected to see this result:

[image]

Because my table contains the following data:

[image]

What am I doing wrong?

The table structure:

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Don't use a single value `in` clause that may cause problem

Comment: How do the classes `Privileges` and `Roles` look like? Shouldn't the Id be unique?

Comment: @Jens Schauder Yes, you are right! The unique ID was not specified in the privilege table. After I added the ID to the entity and added it to the privileges table, all the data was loaded correctly. I added the entities part of the answer and the table structure.